# What is the angle between two orbits in the equatorial plane?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-elements

My orbit is in the equatorial plane. When i apply thrust in the y or x axis, it rotates around the focus or planet - see red and blue orbit in the image below. I know the the semi-major-axis and eccentricity of the ellipse before and after the thrust.

[image: see red and blue orbit]

Please help me to find the angle around the focus.

Note :- Argument of periapsis and ascending node are undefined because the inclination is zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument of periapsis is the in-plane angle between an orbit's periapsis and its ascending node.

It is correct that for an equatorial orbit with an inclination of *exactly* 0° (or 180°), the argument of periapsis is strictly undefined, as is the longitude of the ascending node. In these cases, however, it is *convention* to set the longitude of the ascending node to 0° from some reference direction (typically the vernal equinox for geocentric orbits), meaning we measure the argument of periapsis directly from the reference direction. This is called the [*longitude* of periapsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude_of_the_periapsis) and is used instead of the *argument* of periapsis.

Therefore in the given diagram, both orbits would conventionally have their respective longitude of periapsis measured from the same reference direction, allowing us to differentiate them.

[This document](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/cami/library/online_libraries/aerospace_medicine/tutorial/media/III.4.1.4_Describing_Orbits.pdf) has some great detail on understanding this, page 13 in particular.

Comment: If i set ascending not zero and calculate the argument of apsois , it then just angle theata or angle between the satellite and foci .

Comment: Can you give me an example of calculation.because right ascension also like theata as mentione in above comment.

Comment: Also by Wikipedia , argument of periapsis is zero for such orbits.

Comment: The document I've linked explains this really well. Essentially, because the longitude of ascending node is undefined, we can just pick an arbitrary one and use it, as long as we're consistent between orbits. By convention, we use the longitude which is measured from the vernal equinox.